# Does it matter if I type 'byte' instead of 'Byte' in the below JAVA program? Thank you

Tags: java, class

```
class byte {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte range;

        range = 124;
        System.out.println(range);
    }
}
```

*O/P*:
             Error: Could not find or load main class byte

```
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: byte
```

Comment: Your class name cannot be `byte`. It is a keyword in java.

Comment: @DeanXu You should write this as an answer rather than a comment, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @DeanXu I get it. Thanks! And else there's no problem what class name I give except for the keywords?

Comment: **byte** is a primitive and **Byte** is a Class. You should read this as well: [When to use primitive vs class in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203970/when-to-use-primitive-vs-class-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you are creating a class named `byte` which is a keyword. Also `Byte` is an object in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Byte.html) and `byte` is an primitive type (See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

To make your program work you should change your class name to something different.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, *byte* is a primitive type, *Byte* is an Object, so a *Byte* variable can be set to null.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

*byte* is also a keyword, thus you can't use it to name a variable or a class, your code wouldn't compile.